# RecyclerView does not update the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I'm working on adding an item via a button.

I used `ListAdapter` and `DiffUtil`.

However, when the button is pressed, the first item is updated, but the screen does not update after that.

I tried `debugging` with `Adapter` and `DiffUtil`.

I checked whether the `List` was `submitted` well by using the `currentList` in the Adapter, but the break point works only on the first item and does not stop for the items added after that.

In `DiffUtil`, we confirmed that `break point` does not work at all.

What code did I write wrong?

---

**Fragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentWriteRoutine2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    adapter = DetailAdapter()

    binding.apply {
        rv.adapter = adapter
        rv.itemAnimator = null
        header.add.setOnClickListener {
            vm.addDetail()
        }
        header.delete.setOnClickListener {
            vm.deleteDetail()
        }
    }
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { newList ->
        adapter.submitList(newList)
    }
}
```

**RoutineItem**

```
sealed class RoutineItem(
    val id: String,
) {
    class Header(
        id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val workout: String,
        val unit: String,
    ) : RoutineItem(id)

    class Detail(
        id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val set: Int,
        var weight: String = "",
        var reps: String = "",
    ) : RoutineItem(id)
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class DetailAdapter
    : ListAdapter<RoutineItem, DetailAdapter.ViewHolder>(RoutineDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemRoutineDetailBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cur = currentList
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemRoutineDetailBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: RoutineItem.Detail) {

        }
    }
}
```

**DiffUtilCallback**

```
class DetailDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RoutineItem>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: RoutineItem,
        newItem: RoutineItem
    ): Boolean = (oldItem.id == newItem.id)

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: RoutineItem,
        newItem: RoutineItem
    ): Boolean = (oldItem == newItem)
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we forget to ask the view to redraw using `invalidate()`?

Comment: @clwhisk That's not necessary with ListAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using `data` classes for your Header and Detail classes, their `equals()` functions are inadequate for using `==` in your `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`. A `data` class automatically compares all its constructor properties in `equals`, but a regular class does not. You can either manually write proper `equals` and `hashcode` implementations for them (IntelliJ IDEA can generate it for you), or you can change them to data classes.

Also, sealed interfaces are a bit cleaner to use than sealed classes in most cases. Probably the reason there are so many examples of sealed classes in Kotlin is that sealed interfaces were not supported until relatively recently (Kotlin 1.5).

Here's how you can define your item classes:

```
sealed interface RoutineItem {
    val id: String

    data class Header(
        override val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val workout: String,
        val unit: String,
    ) : RoutineItem

    data class Detail(
        override val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val set: Int,
        var weight: String = "",
        var reps: String = "",
    ) : RoutineItem
}
```

Other than that, the DetailAdapter code you shared looks very incomplete. It makes no actual attempt to bind any data to the views.

Another small tip: Since DiffUtil.ItemCallbacks typically do not carry any state, you can define them as `object`s instead of `class`es so you don't have to call their constructors or have multiple instances of them hanging around.

Comment: thx. The reason the adapter was incomplete was to check whether items were added or deleted, and only to check for debugging.

However, the item addition update is still not done on the screen due to the click event.

I don't know what the problem is...